# How can I model something off of an image?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I'm kind of new to blender, and i haven't used it in a good while..

I'm attempting to create a model of the Woodcrawlers from Gemini Home Entertainment, as I am trying to make a Roblox game based on the series. I've got images of it (plenty out there), how would I use the images to model things?
Images I'm using:

[image: Woodcrawler Image One]

[image: Woodcrawler Image Two]

Comment: Hello, it's not clear what you mean exactly by "how would I use the images to model things", if you want to model the creature you show there are several technics, for example you can extrude a vertex and use the Skin modifier. You can put your image as a Background or Reference image if you want to see it in your 3D view. Or open it in an Image Editor. Also, is your object supposed to be animated?

Comment: Yes, moonboots, it is meant ot be animated